# facebook app redirected from website

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have made a facebook application

I have uploaded all my code on my server, so facebook can retrieve it from there.

All my code is in HTML, php and javascript.

When the user visits www.mywebsite.com/facebook/app they will go to my index.php file.
But if the user types in www.mywebsite.com/facebook/app/pictures/picture.jpg he will see the picture.

Now I want to make sure, this content only can be access through facebook.

So I want to redirect everybody who tries to enter www.mywebsite.com/facebook/app/..../ to my facebook application www.facebook.com/myapp

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is very unreliable you could use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable in php to see if the user typed in the url directly in their browser. It will be empty if the user has typed in the url directly, but i believe it should be set if your page is embedded through facebook.

see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/ for more info

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Will try working with it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it

```
// Saves the original URL
$Origin_URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// The original URL must also contain the word facebook
$face = "facebook";

// Checks if the URL contains 'facebook'
$contains = strpos($Origin_URL,$face);

// If the original url is empty or doesn't contain facebook
// the user will be redirected to the facebook site
if(Origin_URL == "" || $contains === false)
        header("Location: www.facebook.com/website");
```

This is not bulletproof, so try toy with it a little :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).